# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802) in ios 9.2

Tags: ssl

I have developed an universal app in which I am using google services such as Google Maps & Google Analytics. After Xcode 7 (9.0 & 9.1) update I added key **Allow Arbitrary Loads = YES** to ATP Dictionary to my info.plist file which works fine for both devices. But after ios 9.2 update it shows **NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9814)**. But the twist is, it **works fine for iPhone version 9.2 and not working for iPad version 9.2** [Here i have attach my info.plist screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IZNn.png)

Answer (score 0):

try `/usr/bin/nscurl --verbose --ats-diagnostics <host>`

I also see 9814 on iPad 9.2 (but I don't have iPhone) and error was "*The certificate for this server is invalid*" in my case. But it works on iPad if I remove ATS Dictionary at all and as result I am able to upload/download files over https but I cannot get any http resources.